# Where can I get security breach alerts?

Tags: professional-education, zero-day, cve

I've been following a mish-mash of Google News alerts as well as some 'security' influencers on Twitter, but have a feeling there's a more efficient way to deal with this out there...

Comment: Do you mean information about security vulnerabilities, or actual security breaches of organizations? If the latter keep in mind many organizations do not publicize that type of information

Comment: Also I have recently made an App which might help you to get vulnerability notifications, itunes.apple.com/au/app/vulhunter/id742110071?mt=8

Answer (score 7):

- [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures project](http://cve.mitre.org/cve/index.html) (CVE)
- http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure
- http://packetstormsecurity.org/
- http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/ (BugTraq)
- http://www.exploit-db.com/

Various list above have feeds or subscription feature which you can subscribe to get the vulnerability information delivered right to your inbox.

Comment: I like the national vulnerability database, which basically covers the same info as CVE, but you can get an RSS feed. http://nvd.nist.gov/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep yourself about the latest discovered security vulnerabilities, [BugTraq](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1) would probably be your best bet.

If you want to keep track of security breaches of organisations, the news would be your best bet. There is no consolidated resources that provide immediate feedback about such matters that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned that *your* account might have been included in a security breach, you should check out...

https://www.shouldichangemypassword.com

I think it's pretty good. I follow a bot on Twitter that tracks account credential dumps and within 24 hours, an email address in a dump was flagged on shouldichangemypassword.com. It's run by the same people behind AVG antivirus.

By the way, the twitter bot is here:

https://twitter.com/dumpmon